# Is my machine key auto-generated or isolated?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm attempting to share `.ASPXAUTH` cookies between an ASP.NET MVC 4 application (in IIS 7.5) and a service using `HttpListener` on the same host.

The browser presents the cookies to both correctly, but my service receives `System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data.` at `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt`, which I would expect if the two applications were using different machine keys.

So: how do I find out if my machine is configured to use different machine keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default setting of IIS is autogenerate machine-key and isolate per application
you can change this setting globaly in your machine.config or localy (per application) in your web.config

for details please see

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772287(v=ws.10).aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754909(v=ws.10).aspx

You can see the current setting for machine-key in IIS manager. For details, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey.aspx

Comment: Is it safe to specify the machine key or leaving it auto is alright?

Comment: @saurabh64 leaving it on auto is totaly fine. but if you`r running your app in a webfarm (iis load balancing) you have to set it in via web.config in every instance to the same value. otherwise your user will be logged out at random times when your load-balancing redirects them to another instance.